# Entity Framework Parallel async db operation running sequentially

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to run parallel queries in EF core. This is what my POC code looks like

```
    IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query = repo.GetAll();

    IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query1 = repo.GetAll();
    IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query2 = repo.GetAll();
    IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query3 = repo.GetAll();
    IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query4 = repo.GetAll();


    query = CreateIQueryableFromParameters(queryParameters, query);
    query1 = CreateIQueryableFromParameters(queryParameters, query1 );
    query2 = CreateIQueryableFromParameters(queryParameters, query2 );
    query3 = CreateIQueryableFromParameters(queryParameters, query3 );
    query4 = CreateIQueryableFromParameters(queryParameters, query4 );



    var a = query.CountAsync();
    var b = query1.ToListAsync();
    var c = query2.ToListAsync();
    var d = query3.ToListAsync();
    var e = query4.ToListAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(a, b,c,d,e);
```

In C# it is running without waiting for the previous query.
I traced all these in SQL server profiler. The actual db query is running sequentially. Basically the db query generated by `query2` only starts after the query of `query1` ends.

[image]

Is this a normal behavior? How can i achieve true parallelism ?

Comment: No, it's not supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async Not on the same context at least

Comment: 9 times out of 10, if you are doing parallel for the sake of performance you are doing something wrong anyway, databases are the best place (and know better how to ) run database operations in parallel

Comment: It looks like it takes ~20s to run all of them. Why don't you use a single stored procedure call and return multiple result sets?

Comment: @Train I did get an error saying multiple operations are not allowed simultaneously. I think Thats why I am getting a new instance of Iqueryable everytime doing repo.GetAll() to get around that.  On the stored procedure.. Its probably not a good practice to mix EF , linq and stored procedure

Comment: Another option is to load the data into memory before hand and run some async quries in memory.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Can you elaborate more on that in the context of EF?

Comment: A database creates a query plan off a query, it then can use indexes  and break workloads up and can run them parallel, it is limited by everything you are limited by on the user side of your application, I.e Disk IO, CPU, and most likely network IO. Calling into the database for multiple queries that can be batched or combined actually reduces the ability of the database to do what it does best, analyse queries... If the data is so unrelated that they your parallel queries cant be combined, then there are potentially other options like ADO, and Dapper and stored procedures ect.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yes I agree with that also. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This is not for every use case, but its just a rule of thumb i have come to see from Stackoverflow questions, people who are trying to run parallel queries for performance 9 times out of 10 are doing it for the wrong reasons. However this may not be you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anwering my own question

The problem is the shared repo instance.

```
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query = repo.GetAll();
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query1 = repo.GetAll();
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query2 = repo.GetAll();
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query3 = repo.GetAll();
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query4 = repo.GetAll();
```

Althought this will not throw expception due to parallel queries. It will not run query in db in parallel. I had to get new instance of repository for each parallel query  so the solution would be something like

```
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query = repo.GetAll();
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query1 = repo1.GetAll();
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query2 = repo2.GetAll();
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query3 = repo3.GetAll();
IQueryable<ClaimHeader> query4 = repo4.GetAll();
```

This works and verfied in Profiler.